# Connect to a Shared Folder on a new computer

Tags: restore, folder, workspace, connection

I have been using SharePoint Shared Folders as a backup and synching mechanism for my working documents on my laptop.  I created a Shared Folder (I called it "Synchronize") for myself and keep all my working files there.  I am only using 1 laptop.  I recently got a new laptop used my only "groove account file" to invite my new computer to my Shared Folder, and the synchronization of my files began almost immediately. I then had an unrecoverable issue with that laptop and it was unusable (for unrelated reasons) without any warning.  I was not able to generate another "groove account file" before the first new laptop failed; all I have is my original account file.  I now have a new working laptop and am attempting to connect to my Shared Folder using the original account file, and nothing is happening.  SharePoint Workspace stays in the "Downloading" state for hours and nothing downloads or syncs to my new computer.

My user support techs are not familiar with SharePoint Workspace or Shared Folders, and my SharePoint server admins aren't really familiar with it either.  I do understand from them we're not running Groove server or the Groove management console.  They keep asking me for the URL of my SharePoint site and I never had a URL and can't even imagine what it might be.

How can I get to my Shared Folder?

Thanks in advance!